# JSON Increased in Fragment whenever I press back button

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I have a Fragment called HomeFragment contain GridView list from JSON that requested using Volley. And its success without any problem to display the JSON, but the problem is when after i go to another fragment or activity then back again to HomeFragment, the JSON in GridView is increased/added with the same data again.

How to stop that so the data is not increased.

there is my code in HomeFragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);;
    getActivity().setTitle("Dashboard");

    final HashMap<String, String> role = sharedPreference.getDetails();
    String url = "http://myurl";

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject data = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String menu_id = data.getString("menu_id");
                    String menu_name = data.getString("menu_name");

                    HashMap<String, String> row = new HashMap<>();
                    row.put("menu_id", menu_id);
                    row.put("menu_name", menu_name);

                    menulist.add(row);

                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + menulist );

                    GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_grid);
                    ListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getContext(), menulist,
                            R.layout.home_menu, new String[]{"menu_name"},
                            new int[]{R.id.item_grid});
                    gridView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                }
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "error : " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    queue.add(stringRequest);
    return view;
}
```

[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMWi7.png)

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go to another fragment/activity, your HomeFragment doesn't get destroyed immediately, so its values (`menulist`) are still preserved. But when you get back to it, the view is created again, and the new data from the API is added to the previous list.

In your `onResponse()` method, clear the `menulist` with `menulist.clear()`

```
menulist.clear();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("data");
```

This doesn't reduce API calls but keeps the data consistent.

Answer (score 0):

When you go from `HomeFragmnt` to `OtherFragment` and when pressed back `onCreateView()` call again in `HomeFragment` so your request call again so your data is duplicate.

You should Make BaseFragment do the following code. it will help you.

**Java Help**

**BaseFragment.java**

```
public class BaseFragment<T> extends Fragment {

    public boolean hasInitializedRootView = false;

    private View rootView;

    public View getPersistentView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState, int layout){
        if (rootView == null) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(layout, container, false);
        } else {
            ((ViewGroup) rootView.getParent()).removeView(rootView);
        }

        return rootView;
    }
    
}
```

**HomeFragment.java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends BaseFragment<View> {

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return getPersistentView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState, R.layout.fragment_home);
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        if (!hasInitializedRootView) {
            hasInitializedRootView = true;

            // Do your work here

        }

    }
}
```

**Kotlin Help**

**BaseFragment.kt**

```
open class BaseFragment<T : View> : Fragment() {

    var hasInitializedRootView = false
    private var rootView: View? = null

    fun getPersistentView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
        layout: Int
    ): View? {
        if (rootView == null) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(layout, container, false)
        } else {

            (rootView?.parent as? ViewGroup)?.removeView(rootView)
        }

        return rootView
    }

}
```

**HomeFragment.kt**

```
class HomeFragment : BaseFragment<View>() {
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return getPersistentView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState, R.layout.fragment_home)
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        if (!hasInitializedRootView) {
            hasInitializedRootView = true

            // Do your work here

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, so the request is recalled when the fragment is created. Thanks